# How to check if user (login in collection) exists in mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, authentication, database

I want to check, if login is occupied.

This is my code:

```
    $morsy = new MongoCollection($db, 'morsy');
    $sprlogin = array('login' => $login);

    $cursor = $morsy->find($sprlogin);
    $wynik = iterator_to_array($cursor);

    if ($wynik >0){
        $correct=0;
        $_SESSION['e_login']="Ten login jest zajęty.";
    }
```

I found one answer with "`db.users.find()`" function, but I think I did something wrong - my website displayed **Error 500** when I used it.

So if you know what I can do with this method, I would be grateful.

I think it's something wrong with my usage of cursor, but I can't think about what it is exactly.

**ANSWER:**

```
    $morsy = new MongoCollection($db, 'morsy');
    $sprlogin = array('login' => $login);

    $cursor = $morsy->find($sprlogin);
    empty($wynik);
    $wynik = iterator_to_array($cursor);
    if(!empty($wynik)){
        $correct=0;
        $_SESSION['e_login']="Ten login jest zajęty.";
    }
```

Comment: what is the error? (in the logs you have more information about your error 500)

Comment: Maybe I'm just doing something stupid, but console in chrome doesn't show any logs and I'm working on virtual machine and command I am supposed to use there says "there's no such file".
And error was displaying when I used:
`if(db.morsy.find({mors:'login'}).count()>0){
            $correct=0;
            $_SESSION['e_login']="Ten login jest zajęty.";
        }
`

Comment: what do you have in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: To post code in comment you have to add the character ` before and after your statement

Comment: /var/www/prod/web/rejestruj.php on line 15, referer: http://192.168.56.10/forum.php
[Wed Jan 04 20:19:44.032092 2017] [:error] [pid 476] [client 192.168.56.1:24970] PHP 
/var/www/prod/web/rejestruj.php on line 11, referer: http://192.168.56.10/forum.php
[Sat Jan 07 23:17:36.227067 2017] [:error] [pid 2516] [client 192.168.56.1:38010] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: haslo1 in /var/www/prod/web/rejestruj.php on line 19, referer: http://192.168.56.10/forum.php

I think I have more than one problem there...

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm looking for to be honest